# Get a distance from path start to a point along it

Tags: geometry, vectors

It's more a GIS task but here I would like to know how to perform it by use of math in python. I have seen many questions like how to get a coordinate on a path with a given distance from it's start but now I'm trying to go quite an opposite way.

I have a path with coordinates like

```
line_xy = [
 (10.6745, 60.7472),
 (10.8342, 60.468),
 (11.0531, 60.6219),
 (11.6312, 60.437),
 (11.9612, 61.2375),
 (13.0519, 60.8747),
 (13.183, 61.3358)
]
```

There is a point placed on it with a coordinate `pnt_closest_xy = (11.8178, 60.8898)`

My goal is to measure a distance from start of this path to this point along the path itself.
Right now it doesn't matter which length units are used.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

What I did so far:

1. Split my path coordinates into chunks like `[[(x1, y1), (x2, y2) ], [(x2, y2), (x3, y3)], ...]`
2. Made a loop of chunks in which there was a calculation of distance between points in each chunk. Also calculated a distance from chunk's start to a new point and from this point to chunks' end and added a chunk to a new list that would contain coordinates for new line.
3. If both distances from new point to chunks' start and end are less than distance between chunks' coordinates, that means that point in located straight on this particular chunk. A chunk's start and new point coordinate is added to a list of new line and loop is breaking.
4. A new path that goes from start to a new point along path is calculated.

This is how it looks like in python.

```
def distance_pp(pnt_one, pnt_two):
    x_start, y_start = pnt_one
    x_end, y_end = pnt_two
    return math.sqrt((x_end - x_start)**2+(y_end - y_start)**2)

line_chunks = [[line_xy[i-1], v] for i, v in enumerate(line_xy) if i>0] # path coordinates split into chunks 
line_length = sum(distance_xy(ch[0], ch[1]) for ch in line_chunks) # path length 

new_path_ch = []
for ch in line_chunks:
    chunk_start = ch[0]
    chunk_end = ch[1]
    chunk_distance = distance_pp(chunk_start, chunk_end)
    closest_pnt_start = distance_pp(chunk_start, pnt_closest_xy)
    closest_pnt_end = distance_pp(pnt_closest_xy, chunk_end)
    new_path_ch.append(ch)
    if closest_pnt_start<chunk_distance and closest_pnt_start<closest_pnt_end:
        new_path_ch[-1] = [chunk_start , pnt_closest_xy]
        break 
new_line_length = sum(distance_pp(ch[0], ch[1]) for ch in new_path_ch)  # distance from start point to a new point along path
```

This code works for me but I assume that there should be a better solution which is based on math basics.

Comment: Perhaps chunking is not necessary to carry out the computation. However, mathematically speaking, I speculate that your approach is the simplest approach.

Comment: @CarefreeXplorer yeah, I could avoid chunking, but keep them for another calculations.

Comment: The problem divides into two parts: find chunk which is more appropriate, and then find distance. For first part we need to define goal function. For example, it can be distance from point to nearest chunk point. This can be described mathematically. One can calculate this distance from all chunks and select chunk with minimal distance. Then one can add all the lengths of preceding chunks and add distance from end of the last preceding chunk to the point.

Comment: I believe your logic of defining nearest chunk may be not working correctly for some cases.

Comment: You can set some small accuracy parameter $\epsilon$ and check $distance(r_i,r)+distance(r_{i+1},r)\leq distance(r_{i},r_{i+1})+\epsilon$, where $r_i$ is the begin of $i$-th chunk or end of $i-1$-st chunk, $r$ is new point.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu thank you for advice! If I understood you correctly, you recommend firstly to find a nearest chunk to point and then get a distance from this chunk's coodinates to point? Well I just thought that if path is going to be made of hundreds of chunks, it would be generally faster to calculate distances from its start end end to point and if they boith are less than chunk's length, break the loop which means that task is completed.